# Swift, Mac OS X. Uploading large files to s3 bucket AWS.

Tags: swift, macos, amazon-s3

I have my first app on swift and I need to upload large files to s3 bucket. I was trying to upload via [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), but s3 bucket has limit on max file size ( 5 gb) when I use put request. Also I haven't found AWS SDK for Swift. Has anyone any ideas? Thank you!